# Entity Framework Mapping Issue

Tags: entity-framework-6

In my EF code, I am using classes based on the `EntityTypeConfiguration<T>` class to perform configuration.

In these classes, I have helper methods to aid in the configuration.  For example, I have the following code:

```
protected void MapGuidColumn(Expression<Func<T, Guid>> selector, string columnName, bool isRequired, bool isIdentity)
{
  PrimitivePropertyConfiguration configuration = null;

  configuration = this.Property(selector);
  configuration.HasColumnName(columnName);

  if (isRequired == true)
  {
    configuration.IsRequired();
  }
  else
  {
    configuration.IsOptional();
  }

  if (isIdentity == true)
  {
    configuration.HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
  }

  return;
}
```

I call this method using a statement like the following:

```
MapGuidColumn(e => e.ID, "ID", true, true);
```

In the `MapGuidColumn` method, the expression that is actually received is `e => Convert(e).ID` and not `e => e.ID`.  EF seems to have issues with this expression on the statement `configuration = this.Property(selector);`.  It fails with the following exception message:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The expression 'e => Convert(e).ID' is not a valid property expression. The expression should represent a property: C#: 't => t.MyProperty'  VB.Net: 'Function(t) t.MyProperty'. Use dotted paths for nested properties: C#: 't => t.MyProperty.MyProperty'  VB.Net: 'Function(t) t.MyProperty.MyProperty'.

I have used this method in the past but never really looked the expression that is received by the helper methods.  However, this is the first time I have run into this issue.

Can someone point me in the direction as to what might be happening here?  I can provide more code if necessary (I am just not sure what to provide at this point).

Comment: I think the exception message is pretty clear. `Convert(e).ID` is not a property of `e`. What's the purpose of this expression?

Comment: If you look at standard `OnModelCreating` method of the `DbContext` class, you can write a statement such as `modelBuilder.Entity<T>().Property(e => e.ID).HasColumnName("ID");` where T is a model class.  What I am doing with the help method above is wrap these types of statements together.  If you look at the `Property` method in this statement, it requires an instance of `Expression<Func<T, U>>`.  The helper method above requires an instance of the same type.  Essentially, the question is why does it work when using OnModelCreating but not with my helper method.

Comment: But you can't write `modelBuilder.Entity<T>().Property(e => Convert(e).ID)`. I don't understand why you expect it to work only because the expression satisfies the signature. Or maybe I'm just not following you.

Comment: When I call the `Property` method, I call it with the expression `e => e.ID`.  When I call my helper method, I call it with the expression `e => e.ID`.  I am assuming that the actual expression that is received by the `Property` method is indeed `e => e.ID`.  I cannot *easily* confirm this as I don't (currently) have the source code for EF.  I can confirm that the expression that is received by my helper method is not `e => e.ID` (which is what I passed in) but instead is `e => Convert(e).ID`.

Comment: To continue my last comment, if I can figure out why the expression that is passed to my helper method is not the expression that is received by my helper method (why it is getting changed / converted) I will be on the right track.